# Django celery task run at once on startup of celery server

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I need to find how to specify a kind of initial celery task, that will start all other tasks in specially defined way. This initial task should be run immediately at once on celery server startup and never run again.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about using [`celeryd_after_setup`](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#celeryd-after-setup) or [`celeryd_init`](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#celeryd-init) signal?

Follwing example code from the documentation:

```
from celery.signals import celeryd_init

@celeryd_init.connect(sender='worker12@example.com')
def configure_worker12(conf=None, **kwargs):
    ...
```

Comment: I can see that you are trying to change some configuration of a worker, but still don't understand how will that affect the task.  @falsetru Can you share the  complete code, which can show the relation to the task ?

Comment: @Abhimanyu, I think I already provided enough code. ;) How about post a separate question instead of comment so that others can answer you?

Comment: @falsetru why does it mention a specific worker? Why there is no task launch code?

Comment: @Velkan, It's originated from celeryd_init example. Please follow the links for more detail.

Comment: @falsetru oh, that will be called for every worker. Is there something to just run a task exactly once and never again?

Comment: @Velkan, Like given example code, how about specify `sender` to run on specific worker. if you want it don't run next time worker start, you need to persist run state somewhere (for example in DB.)

Answer (score -1):

I found the way to do this. It has one negative side - impossible to specify current year and task will run after year again. But usually server restarts more often, then this period.

```
from celery.task import PeriodicTask

class InitialTasksStarter(PeriodicTask):
    starttime = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=1)
    run_every = crontab(month_of_year=starttime.month, day_of_month=starttime.day, hour=starttime.hour, minute=starttime.minute)

    def run(self, **kwargs):
        ....
        return True
```